# Operator ^ cannot be applied to operands of type float and int

Tags: c#

Problem definition: design a class `BankAccount (accountno, name)`. Inherit this class in `FixedDeposit` class which has data members like principal amount (P), rate of interest (R), no. of years (N).

Allow users to input P, R, N and calculate Due Amount (A) and interest (I).

Formulas

```
A = P(1 + R / 100) ^ N    and   I = A - P
```

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace prac_18
{
    public class BankAccount
    {
        int accno;
        string name;
    }

    public class FixedDeposit : BankAccount
    {
        float pamt;
        float roi;
        int years;

        public  void getdata(float p,float r,int y)
        {
            pamt = p;
            roi = r;
            years = y;
        }

        public float calc_due()
        {
             float amt = 0;
             amt = pamt * (1 + roi / 100)^years;   // Here I get the error
             return amt;
        }

        public float calc_intrest()
        {
             float  intrest = 0;
             intrest = calc_due() - pamt;
             return intrest;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you expect "^" to do?

Comment: i want to use power for calculating due amount

Comment: `^` is a binary XOR operator in C#, not the exponential. You need `Math.Pow()`.

Comment: You need to use Math.Pow  ^ has a whole new meaning in coding languages

Comment: The ^ operator is a logical XOR. If you were looking for an exponential operator, there isn't one - have a look at `Math.Pow` instead.

Comment: oh thanks, sir, it will help me to improve my code

Comment: `amt = Math.Pow(pamt * (1 + roi / 100), years)` is what you are after. When you move past `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/` it's helpful to read the manual/ask google as each language has a different syntax for dealing with math.

Answer (score 1):

In C# the ^ operator is Exclusive OR - so cannot be used with float & int.

But it looks like you want to use it to raise a value by a power, so you want to use [Math.Pow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 amt = pamt * Math.Pow((1 + roi / 100), years);
```

Comment: thanks a lot sir!!

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted, but this question was always going to be a duplicate.